# PostgreSQLSeverity.error 42601: syntax error at end of input in flutter

Tags: flutter, input, syntax

Code:

```
var result = await neonClient.query(query: 'INSERT INTO stores (store_name,phone,mobile,store_type,img,time_from,time_to,location_store,location_path) VALUES ($store_name,$phone,$mobile, $store_type,$img,$time_from,$time_to,$location_store,$location_path);').then((value) async {

    print(value);

  }).onError((error, stackTrace) async {

    print('$error');

    await neonClient.close();

  }).whenComplete(() async {

    await neonClient.close();

  });
```

``

I try to put static value.

Comment: Try removing the semicolon here: `$location_path);'`